# How to show only 5 rows of data from 100 in angular 8 HTML and sort them directly while displaying on screen in descending order

Tags: html, angular, angular8

[image]

I've used [row] attribute but still not working and when the data reflects on UI I want it in descending order. Can anyone please let me know how it is done without adding sorting Icon?

More
               
                
                    
                        
                            
                                {{col.header}}
                                
                            
                        
                    
                    
            
                
                    {{rowData[col.field]}}

```
        </tr>

    </ng-template>-->
                <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
                    <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
                        <td style="width:300px">{{rowData.atomName}} </td>
                        <td style="width:300px" (click)="show(rowData.message,op2.show($event))" pTooltip="View" tooltipPosition="top" tooltipStyleClass="custom-tooltip">
                            {{rowData.processName}}<!--</td>-->
                            <!--<td style="width:20px">-->

                            

                        </td>
                        <td style="width:20px">
                            <!--{{rowData.executionTime}}-->
                            {{rowData.executionTime | date :'MM/dd/yyyy' }} ({{rowData.executionTime | date :'h:mm:ss a'  }})
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
               
            </p-table>
        </p-panel>
       
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. It looks more like Angular Js than Angular 8 but if referring to Angular 8 -
   Only possible solution to this is sort in the TS file using Array Sort (refer link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). and then display only 5 top results using *ngFor and index inside *ngFor.